# C++ segmentation fault badly detected by debugger

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, segmentation-fault

Below is beginning of my c++ program. It looks quite normal for me but when I run it I gets segmentation fault. This is what the debugger gives me:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008d4 in main () at usu.cpp:12
12      cin >> n >> k;
```

But the errer isn't connected with this line of code becouse when I put "reutrn 1" before for loop programs ends normally. What could be wrong? I compiling my program using: g++ -ggdb3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_N 1000000
#define MAX_K 1000000
#define MAX_IL_KROKOW 500000

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k;   
    cin >> n >> k;

    char klocki[MAX_N+1];
    int Przes_C[MAX_IL_KROKOW];//podaje następne c po c znajdującym się na pozycji i
    int Ktore_b[MAX_N];//na podstawie indeksu b w klockach zwraca indeks w tablicy Przes_b
    int Przes_b[MAX_N];//zwraca indeks b w klockach na podstawie występowania b 
    int poprz_c = -1;
    int ilosc_b = 0;
    int klocki_len = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {   
        klocki[i] = getchar();
        return 1;
        if(klocki[i] == 'b')
        {   
            Przes_b[ilosc_b] = i;
            Ktore_b[i] = ilosc_b;
            ilosc_b++;
        }       
        if(poprz_c != -1 && klocki[i] == 'c')
            Przes_C[poprz_c] = i;
        if(klocki[i] == 'c')
            poprz_c = i; 

        klocki_len++;
    }       
    klocki[klocki_len] = '\0';
```

Comment: BTW If you are using C++ you should include <cstdio> instead of <stdio.h>

Answer (score 5):

It's likely youur array allocation fails which leads to undefined behaviour when you try to write something to the arrays.

```
char klocki[MAX_N+1];
int Przes_C[MAX_IL_KROKOW];
int Ktore_b[MAX_N];
int Przes_b[MAX_N];
```

These are massive arrays. There's only a fixed size of stack allocated per process. Created dynamic arrays using `new`.

Comment: std::vector<int> would be even better.

Comment: Why std::vector would be better than dynamic arrays? Is it faster or just simpler.

Comment: @SzymonOlewniczak Because std::vector has advantages than new: containers are safer, handle memory mgmt for you, size grows automatically when you push to vector etc.

Comment: @KingsIndian "There's only a fixed size of stack allocated per process" is *incorrect* on most operating systems I know. The problem is most likely related to stack overflow, but the overflow is likely not happening because of "fixed stack size".

Comment: @EmployedRussian Not sure if I understand you. On my Linux it's 8MB by default (can be changed of course). Since OP is allocating gigantic arrays, the likely reason he's overflowing whatever the size of stack allocated for the process on his platform.

Comment: @KingsIndian Your *particular* version of Linux is configured with `ulimit -s 8192`. What happens with `ulimit -s unlimited`? The OP program will still crash, but there is no longer any "fixed stack size".

Answer (score 3):

You could also define the array variables as global variables outside the main function. Depends on your program (length) whether that makes sense.

Comment: If you don't need them outside of `main()`, it would be better to define them as `static`.